# Is there a way to get notified when a dart stream gets its first result?

Tags: flutter, dart

I currently have an `async` function that does the following:

1. Initializes the stream
2. Call `stream.listen()` and provide a function to listen to the stream.
3. `await` for the stream to get its first result.

The following is some pseudo code of my function:

```
Future<void> initStream() async {
  // initialize stream
  var stream = getStream();
  // listen
  stream.listen((result) {
    // do some stuff here
  });
  // await until first result
  await stream.first; // gives warning
}
```

Unfortunately it seems that calling `stream.first` counts as listening to the stream, and streams are not allowed to be listened by multiple...listeners?

I tried a different approach by using `await Future.doWhile()`
Something like the following:

```
bool gotFirstResult = false;
Future<void> initStream() async {
  var stream = getStream();
  stream.listen((result) {
    // do some stuff here
    gotFirstResult = true;
  });
  await Future.doWhile(() => !gotFirstResult);
}
```

This didn't work for me, and I still don't know why. `Future.doWhile()` was successfully called, but then the function provided to `stream.listen()` was never called in this case.

Is there a way to wait for the first result of a stream?
(I'm sorry if I didn't describe my question well enough. I'll definitely add other details if needed.)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way is converting your stream to broadcast one:

```dart
var stream = getStream().asBroadcastStream();
stream.listen((result) {
  // do some stuff here
});
await stream.first;
```

Answer (score 8):

Another way, without creating new stream, is to use [Completer](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.2/dart-async/Completer-class.html). It allows you to return a Future which you can *complete* (send value) later. Caller will be able to await this Future as usual.

Simple example:

```dart
Future<int> getValueAsync() {
  var completer = Completer<int>();
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1))
    .then((_) {
      completer.complete(42);
    });
  return completer.future;
}
```

is equivalent of

```dart
Future<int> getValueAsync() async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  return 42;
}
```

In your case:

```dart
Future<void> initStream() {
  var stream = getStream();
  var firstValueReceived = Completer<void>();
  stream.listen((val) {
    if (!firstValueReceived.isCompleted) {
      firstValueReceived.complete();
    }
    // do some stuff here
  });
  return firstValueReceived.future;
}
```